# After installing Ubuntu 14.04 Over windows 8.1 i'm unable to boot from my DVD Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-8

Fun story, i had Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 both installed on my pc. When attempting to re install it detected Ubuntu and said if i wanted to replace that i was like ooh nice, now i don't have to change partitions and stuff. Instead in installed it over everything on the drive. after that i thought i'd just re install windows 8.1 again and then do the dual boot again.. But now even when i change the boot order it for some reason won't go into the windows installation. Can anyone help me with this? Because i'm really clueless and need windows on my pc for Visual Studio 2013 (school related)...

Comment: How are you trying to boot?  Do you press a key ([F12] most of the time) and then boot?  Or did you try re-arrange the boot order in BIOS?  If the latter, try the boot key at start-up anyway, because some BIOSes have a timing issue and boot the HD is the DVD doesn't spin up fast enough...

Comment: @Fabby i did not test the F12 key yet but did just test it and even after getting that menu and selecting the disc, it still did not go to the installation and went to Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post the output of `fdisk -l` in your question and put the contents of /boot/grub/grub.cfg in http://paste.ubuntu.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, the problem was that my bios was set to the new windows 8 UEFI boot mode and i needed to set it to legacy. (UEFI is the new thing with windows 8 i believe)